# Pinescript alerts triggering without condition met

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, alerts

I created a simple ichimoku cloud strategy script for buy only, and limited to trigger only once per day given the specific time, and added the alert to only present when buy triggers.   However alerts tiger more than once when there is no conditions being met. The strategy is not repainting. Not sure why it alerts triggers more than once.

```
    //@version=5
strategy('Test', overlay=true,max_bars_back=500,pyramiding=0)

//Inputs
ts_bars = input.int(9, minval=1, title='Tenkan-Sen Bars')
ks_bars = input.int(26, minval=1, title='Kijun-Sen Bars')
ssb_bars = input.int(52, minval=1, title='Senkou-Span B Bars')
cs_offset = input.int(26, minval=1, title='Chikou-Span Offset')
ss_offset = input.int(26, minval=1, title='Senkou-Span Offset')
long_entry = input(true, title='Long Entry')
short_entry = input(true, title='Short Entry')

middle(len) =>
    math.avg(ta.lowest(len), ta.highest(len))

// Ichimoku Components
tenkan = middle(ts_bars)
kijun = middle(ks_bars)
senkouA = math.avg(tenkan, kijun)
senkouB = middle(ssb_bars)

// Plot Ichimoku Kinko Hyo
// plot(tenkan, color=color.new(#0496ff, 0), title='Tenkan-Sen')
// plot(kijun, color=color.new(#991515, 0), title='Kijun-Sen')
// plot(close, offset=-cs_offset + 1, color=color.new(#459915, 0), title='Chikou-Span')
// sa = plot(senkouA, offset=ss_offset - 1, color=color.new(color.green, 0), title='Senkou-Span A')
// sb = plot(senkouB, offset=ss_offset - 1, color=color.new(color.red, 0), title='Senkou-Span B')
// fill(sa, sb, color=senkouA > senkouB ? color.green : color.red, title='Cloud color', transp=90)

ss_high = math.max(senkouA[ss_offset - 1], senkouB[ss_offset - 1])
ss_low = math.min(senkouA[ss_offset - 1], senkouB[ss_offset - 1])

// Entry/Exit Signals
tk_cross_bull = tenkan > kijun
tk_cross_bear = tenkan < kijun
cs_cross_bull = ta.mom(close, cs_offset - 1) > 0
cs_cross_bear = ta.mom(close, cs_offset - 1) < 0
price_above_kumo = close > ss_high
price_below_kumo = close < ss_low

bullish = tk_cross_bull and cs_cross_bull and price_above_kumo
bearish = tk_cross_bear and cs_cross_bear and price_below_kumo


//=====================================================================================================
buyCondition = bullish
sellCondition = bearish
//======================================================================================================
buyPos  = strategy.position_size >  0
sellPos = strategy.position_size <  0
inPos   = strategy.position_size != 0
noPos   = strategy.position_size == 0
price   = strategy.position_avg_price

//======================================================================================================
var float buy_en = na
var float buy_en = na
var float buy_sl = na
var float buy_tp = na

var float sell_en = na
var float sell_sl = na
var float sell_tp = na

//=========================================================================================================
buySignal = false  
sellSignal = false

buyExitSignal = false
sellExitSignal = false

buyExitCondition = false
sellExitCondition = false

//============================================================================================================
sessionTime = input.session("0700-1000","Trade Time", inline="starttime")
sessionBg = input.bool(false, "change background color for trade session")
timeWindow = time(timeframe.period, sessionTime)
tradeTime = na(timeWindow) ? false : true

GetPipSize() =>
    syminfo.mintick * (syminfo.type == "forex" ? 10 : 1)


slPerc = input.int(5, "Sl pips", group="--- risk / reward ---") * (GetPipSize())
tpPerc = input.int(8, "Tp pips", group="--- risk / reward ---") * (GetPipSize())


//================================================================================================================

strategy.risk.max_intraday_filled_orders(count=2)

//===============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
//BUY BUY 

if buyCondition and noPos and tradeTime and barstate.isconfirmed
    buySignal := true
    strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long)
    alert('BUY', alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
    

if buyPos and not buyPos[1]
    buy_en := price
    buy_sl := price - slPerc
    buy_tp := price + tpPerc
    strategy.exit("exit buy", "buy", stop=buy_sl, limit=buy_tp)
    
if buyPos[1] and not buyPos
    buyExitSignal := true
```

Answer (score 0):

Your alerts trigger multiple times because your `buyCondition` is `true` for multiple bars.

You can check this if you add these two lines to your code:

```
plotshape(buyCondition and noPos and tradeTime)  // Whenever you see these shapes, you will get an alert
bgcolor(buyCondition and tradeTime ? color.new(color.green, 85) : na)
```

[image]

You are using `strategy.risk.max_intraday_filled_orders(count=2)` but your if condition that triggers the alert does not have any checks for the number of intraday filled orders.

Your if condition evaluates to `true` and your alert gets triggered. However, since you reached to the maximum number of trades per day, you don't see the new open position on your chart.

You can use the `alert_message` parameter of the `strategy.entry()` function to trigger the alerts when a position is opened.

Comment: i have using the alert_message.But still shows additional triggers.  One response above, are you stating the the strategy.risk.max_intraday_filled_orders(count=2) be the cause of these additional alerts?

Comment: The `alert()` function will be called whenever `buyCondition` is `true`. It becomes `true` multiple times during the day. That is the reason.

Comment: `strategy.risk.max_intraday_filled_orders` is the reason why you don't see any additional trades even though `buyCondition` is `true`.